# Cakephp join table in my View

Tags: cakephp, join, view

I need you help please!

My view didn't work with my `INNER JOIN`

```
public function view($bk_id = null) 
{   
    $data = $this->Book->findBybk_id($bk_id, array(
        'recursive' => -1,
        'fields' => array('Book.*', 'Article.*'),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'Articles',
                'alias' => 'Article',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array('Article.bk_id = Book.bk_id')
            )
        )
    ));
    $this->set('Book', $data);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: "didn't work" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using [Cake's `findBy` magic functions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby) which don't take a second parameter. Try using [`find('first')`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first) with the relevant conditions instead:-

```
$data = $this->Book->find('first', array(
    'recursive' => -1,
    'fields' => array('Book.*', 'Article.*'),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'Articles',
            'alias' => 'Article',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array('Article.bk_id = Book.bk_id')
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Book.bk_id' => $bk_id
    )
));
```